# Wiremock unit test failing locally - java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, jenkins, wiremock

I have this test in my project which is using Wiremock and it's working correctly in Jenkins (during build time, the test is executing and passing) but it's failing in my local machine with the following error (Eclipse console):

```
14:06:17,692  INFO [org.mortbay.log] - Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
14:06:17,751  INFO [org.mortbay.log] - jetty-6.1.26
14:06:17,767  WARN [org.mortbay.log] - failed DelayableSocketConnector@0.0.0.0:62344: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
14:06:17,767  WARN [org.mortbay.log] - failed Server@549b6220: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
14:06:17,775  INFO [org.mortbay.log] - jetty-6.1.26
14:06:17,776  WARN [org.mortbay.log] - failed DelayableSocketConnector@0.0.0.0:62344: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
14:06:17,776  WARN [org.mortbay.log] - failed Server@1c1474ea: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
14:06:17,777  INFO [org.mortbay.log] - jetty-6.1.26
14:06:17,778  WARN [org.mortbay.log] - failed DelayableSocketConnector@0.0.0.0:62344: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
14:06:17,778  WARN [org.mortbay.log] - failed Server@34c7e8a7: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
```

(Maven)

```
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 3, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.408 sec <<< FAILURE!
Time elapsed: 0.377 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.WireMockServer.start(WireMockServer.java:188)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.junit.WireMockClassRule$1.evaluate(WireMockClassRule.java:75)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:35)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ClassLoaderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:103)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:150)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireStarter.java:91)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:69)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:383)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:328)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:194)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.newServerSocket(SocketConnector.java:80)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.open(SocketConnector.java:73)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:283)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.doStart(SocketConnector.java:147)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:235)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.WireMockServer.start(WireMockServer.java:186)
    ... 21 more
```

I debugged the code to check for errors in my tests, but I can't even get there, since it's failing in the creation of WireMockClassRule (see code below).

```
private static int VVS_PORT_MOCK;
static {
    try {
        VVS_PORT_MOCK = (new ServerSocket(0)).getLocalPort();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //
    }
}

@Rule
public static WireMockClassRule wireMockRule = new WireMockClassRule(VVS_PORT_MOCK);
```

The problem seems to be in the dynamic assignment of the port, cause if I hardcode a port value:

```
 private static int VVS_PORT_MOCK = 8989; //using this it works
```

All the test are passing with no problems (but since this is a unit test, I'm trying to avoid hardcoding it, because I want to ensure that the test will pass everywhere).

(I checked with netstat to see if the port assigned was being used before, but there's no problem there)

I'm thinking it has to do with some local configuration that I'm missing, but I'm lost at this point.

Any ideas of what may be happening?

Also, please let me know if further information is required to address this issues.

Thnaks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ServerSocket is retaining the port when you run the method "getLocalPort()" and when the code is instantiating the WireMockClassRule the port is already binded, causing the Exception that you are facing.

You can change the code block provided with something like this:

```
ServerSocket ss = null;
try {
    ss = new ServerSocket(0);
    PORT = ss.getLocalPort();
} catch (IOException e) {
    LOG.error("Socket Exception while opening socket:", e);
} finally {
    try {
        ss.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.error("Socket Exception while closing socket:", e);
    }
}
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: This actually works perfectly. And it works cross platform. Odd enough, the error it was only happening when running on Windows. It was working correctly in Unix. But this fix makes it run correctly in all the environments. Thanks!